# Save Alexa typed commands

Tags: command, save, alexa-skills-kit

I would like to be able to create an button/icon that when pressed will execute pre-typed command, similar to using the Alexa App keyboard and then pressing save so the same command can be submitted as required. Is there any way of doing this?

searched everywhere I could think of but no luck

Answer (score 0):

As you've probably found, Amazon doesn't officially support this kind of use case. However, the Home Assistant community has created the `alexapy` python library that lets you say any command to Alexa programmatically.

https://pypi.org/project/alexapy/

Again, Amazon doesn't support this so do heed the warning in the library readme.

> NOTE: Alexa has no official API; therefore, this library may stop working at any time without warning.

Comment: Looks promising, thanks for the pointer will take a look